# Sonos websocket can't understand my ping response

Tags: sonos

I'm trying to maintain a connection with Sonos using LAN WebSocket API.

I'm connected to 1443 port and upgrade the connection.

I receive a ping.
[ 0x89, 0x00 ]

I send pong response message.
[ 0x8A, 0x00 ]

The actual result is "close message" with cause 1002. But with simulator is good working.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's time answer for my question.
You must have send masking bit and mask even without data in pong message.
The example is [0x8A, 0x80, 0xFC, 0x3A, 0x67, 0x65].

Comment: Recently i meet same question.As your answer, i resolve it. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited] We don't publicly support connections over WebSockets on the LAN. See [Control Sonos Players](https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/) for details on how to connect through the Sonos cloud.